# Shouldn't "Only during totality...is it safe to look" be "...it is safe to look"?

Tags: grammaticality, word-order, inversion

In the book "Horizons: exploring the universe-Cengage learning (2018)", it said:

> Only during totality, when the photosphere is completely hidden, **is it safe to look** at the Sun
> directly.

So I was wondering why the author wrote "is it safe ... directly." Is it correct in terms of grammar? Shouldn't it be "it is safe.. directly."?

Comment: Related question on EL&U: [Inversion in "only {adverb} have they"](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/62208/80039)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The author wrote it that way because they had chosen to 'invert' the sentence to emphasise the phrase *only during totality.*

Normally, the sentence would read :

> It is safe to look directly at the Sun only during totality.

...but when the *only* phrase is moved to the beginning, the convention is to change the order of the words in the main clause.

> Only when I'm in the country do I feel really happy.

Comment: Well, your second sentence may not be a great example, because the uninverted version would drop the "do" entirely: "I feel really happy only when I'm in the country."

Comment: @ColleenV - OK, granted.